# How to access flag passed to npm script

Tags: node.js, npm

In my package json I created a seed script which uses mocha to initialize my environment and then run a bunch of database calls:

```
"seed": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha seed/seed-bootstrap.js seed/seed.js"
```

I want to be able to pass a flag to this which specifies a seed number that will determine how many of each object will be created so I could run

```
npm run script --seedNum=10
```

and have 10 of each object created.

I just can't figure out how to access the value of seedNum inside my script. I thought it would be in process.argv but it is not. process.argv seems to only contain the contents of my mocha.opts file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so:

`npm run seed -- --seedNum=4`

as per

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Apparently the first `--` is used by npm as a delimiter for the arguments intended for npm and the arguments thereafter intended for your script.

Comment: Works great! One question though:
Right now I'm grabbing that value via: process.argv[process.argv.length - 1]

Is there a better way to access this value?

Comment: The simple answer is "nope".  The  javascript fu answer is "don't index your  argv array dynamically (by doing the length - 1 calculation) unless you know you'll only ever need the last argument passed to your script; just start by indexing it at 2".  If you're doing  anything complicated, maybe   look into using a command line interface library. Or passing config via env variables (process.env).